# How to Enable Remote Shell On SUSE Linux

Tags: linux, remote-access, sles, rsh

I wanted to run remote commands on a suse linux machine from another redhat linux machine. How to enable SUSE to listen to this remote shell commands ?

In normal linux i need to start the service rshd how about in SUSE Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rsh? 80's called, they need their protocols back. Use `ssh`.

In SUSE you can temporarily (that means, until next reboot) start ssh daemon with `service sshd start`. Should you need it to start automatically at boot time, use `chkconfig sshd on`.

Comment: +1 for making me laugh :)

Comment: Thank You So Much. I am not so mach acquainted with Linux........